# Which Activity inflated CustomAdapter?

Tags: android

I have two activities, activityA and activityB each with a custom listview using the same `CustomAdapter`. Can `CustomAdapter` know which activity inflated it?

Answer (score 1):

You can know it using `Context` of the `CustomAdapter`

```
if (context instanceof ActivityA) {
    //It was A
}
else if (context instanceof ActivityB) {
    //It was B
}
```